How to get rid of progress dialog while saving excel file in c#
I'm trying to change and save Excel file in C#. Everything is ok, but a progress dialog appears while the file is being saved. How can I rid of this progress dialog - I have to run the code from Windows service.
            var excelType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
            dynamic excel = Activator.CreateInstance(excelType);
            excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
            excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename: path);
            // ......
            // do job
            // ......
            excel.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
            excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(Filename: path);
            // this behaves the same
            //excel.ActiveWorkbook.Save();



This usage isn't supported. See Considerations for server-side Automation of Office which states: Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component...

Try -

public void SaveExcelFile(string path)
{
    // Create an instance of Excel application
    var excelType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
    dynamic excel = Activator.CreateInstance(excelType);

    try
    {
        // Suppress alerts and make Excel invisible
        excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
        excel.Visible = false;

        // Open the workbook
        excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename: path);

        // Perform your operations here
        // ...

        // Mark workbook as saved to avoid prompt
        excel.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;

        // Save the workbook without showing any dialogs
        excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(Filename: path);

        // Alternatively, you can use Save if the file already exists
        // excel.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
    }
    finally
    {
        // Clean up resources
        if (excel != null)
        {
            excel.Quit();
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
        }
    }
}


Unfortunately, the progress window still appears

I feel bad. but let me figure out.
